# Why do accountExpires and userAccountControl filters in SpringLDAP / plain Java AD queries do not work as expected?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, active-directory, jndi, spring-ldap

I'm using `SpringLDAP` API within spring based webapp to query ActiveDirectory that is hosted on Windows Server 2012. Following are my environment details :-
`Java 1.8.0_101`, `apache-tomcat-8.0.36`, `SpringMVC 4.3.1` & `SpringLDAP 2.3.1`

The following AD filter query fetches the matching accounts in windows based (C++/C# based) query tool (e.g., Lepide AD Query tool) and also in the LDAP Browser plugin within the eclipse IDE BUT **does not fetch the matching records/AD accounts** when used within the Java (JNDI/SpringLDAP API based) code & also in the Java based application **JXplorer** :-

```
(&(objectclass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(accountExpires>=131554368000000000)(userPrincipalName=cgm@*))
```

I'm trying to get an user account that is ACTIVE, not yet expired given a date and with `userPrincipalName` value starting with string `cgm@`.

Following is the ldap configuration within the `spring-servlet.xml` file :-

```
<util:map id="ldapBaseEnvProps">
        <entry key="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary" value="objectGUID"/>
</util:map>
<ldap:context-source id="pooledLdapContextSrc" url="ldap://dc.myadserver.com:3268" base="DC=myadserver,DC=com" username="CN=adusername,OU=Mkt-Managers,DC=myadserver,DC=com" password="*****" base-env-props-ref="ldapBaseEnvProps">
    <ldap:pooling max-total="16" max-active="16" max-idle="8" min-idle="0" max-wait="90000" when-exhausted="BLOCK" test-on-borrow="true" test-while-idle="true"/>
</ldap:context-source>
```

Are such AD filters supported by Java/SpringLDAP API at all? If yes, what needs to be changed for the above AD query filter to work (fetch matching AD account(s)) in the Java based code?

Comment: please be more specific, what do you mean by 'It does not work'?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Spring LDAP's query builder object in Java to help you build that query. Your question seems to indicate that you copied that query from your C (windows) environment into your Java environment.

I would start by building the query with .where() function in Spring LDAP as used here and seeing if it results in the same error:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/query/LdapQueryBuilder.html